# How to measure time between clicks?

Tags: java, android

I want to make a simple timer that will when I click `button`starts timing and when I click second time on the button I get elapsed time in milliseconds to `textView`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int i = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            i++;
            if (i >= 2)
            {
                long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long diff = end - start;
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(diff));
            }
        }
    });

}
```

> > I get value of 0 when I launch app

Comment: Yeah, you're already measuring what you want, so what is your question?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing now?

Comment: @SuhyeonLee I get value of 0

Comment: it's because you saved the start time in your listener. make the `start` outside of the listener.

Comment: @SuhyeonLee Wow thats it, it fixed my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private long start = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (start > 0) {
                long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long diff = end - start;
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(diff));
                start = 0;
            } else {
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You save the `start` each time you click the button, so `start` and `end` should be almost the same.

```
final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
long start = -1;
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(start < 0)
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        else {
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long diff = end - start;
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(diff));
            start = -1;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   int i = 1;
   long start,end;

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (i == 2)
            {
                end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long diff = end - start;
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(diff));
                i = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                i++;
            }
        }
    });
```